# About estimators and Bernoulli distribution

Tags: bias, bernoulli-distribution

I have this homework question which I'm not understanding. It goes as follows: Let $X_1,\dots, X_n$ be a random sample with Bernoulli distribution of parameter $p$ and let $T_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Let $\theta := p(1-p)$.

a) Show that $\bar{p} := T_n (n - T_n) / (n(n-1))$ is unbiased.

This I already did.

b) Compute the Maximum Likelihood Estimator for $\theta$.

I'm not sure if I should calculate the MLE for $p$, let's call it $\hat{p}$, and then just return $\hat{p} (1-\hat{p})$. Would that be correct? Because maximizing the probability of the sample relative to $p$ isn't the same that relative to $p(1-p)$.

c) Show that the MLE for $\theta$ is biased but asintotically unbiased.

This I feel comfortable with.

d) Show that $\bar{p}$ has greater variance than the MLE. Observer that this can be shown without calculating $V(\bar{p})$.

This is the question I'm struggling most with. Am I supposed to use a strong theorem I don't know, that relates variance and bias?

Comment: You must have left out something crucial from your problem statement: exactly what property of the distribution is $\theta$??  It looks like $\theta=p(1-p),$ but your answer to (a) suggests $\theta=p.$

Comment: thanks, $\theta = p(1-p)$, I had left it out.

Comment: Thank you.  To answer (d)--which is really your only outstanding question--you can relate the estimator in (a) to the MLE and, in particular, compare their variances even without knowing the variance of either one.  This suggests you are expected to know something about variances--or at least asymptotic variances--of Maximum Likelihood estimates.

Comment: Note: Your answer in part b) is correct due to the *invariance property* of the MLE. That is, if $\tau = g(\theta)$ and $\hat\theta$ is the MLE of $\theta$, then $g(\hat\theta)$ is the MLE of $\tau$.